# Having issues with importing model to another app in order to use model there

Tags: python, django

My project structure:

ecomarket:

- ecomarket:
- cart:
- product:
- user:
  manage.py

Here's product.models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Называние"), max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Описание"), null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name=_("Цена"), max_digits=9, decimal_places=2
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_("Количество"), default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        "Category", verbose_name=_("Категория"), on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
```

And this is cart.models

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s cart"


class CartProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("product.Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=9, verbose_name=_("Общая цена")
    )
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cart_products")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, verbose_name=_("Количество"))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

The issue is when I'm importing Product in the top of file like **from product.models import** the django is refusing to understand it. In cart.models I imported Product model in ForeignKey as a string and it worked. But I need Product model in my cart.views to create when endpoint get request. So how can I import it to my cart.views?

Here's my views.py

```
class AddToCartView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        quantity = request.data.get("quantity")
        id = kwargs.get('id')
        user = request.user
        product = generics.get_object_or_404("product.Product", id=id)
        cart, _ = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        cart_product = CartProduct.objects.filter(
            product=product, cart=cart
            )

        if cart_product:
            raise exceptions.NotAcceptable(
                'You already have this product in your cart'
                )

        if quantity > product.quantity:
            raise exceptions.NotAcceptable(
                "Not enough product in stock!!! We'll restock it ASAP"
                )
        cart_product = CartProduct.objects.get_or_create(
            product=product, quantity=quantity, cart=cart
            )
        total_price = product.price * quantity
        cart.total_price += total_price
        cart.save()
        return response.Response(
            {'message': 'You successfully added product into your cart'},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
```

Thank you for all answers in advance

While searching I learned that it's because of python's new version, But couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Django is refusing to understand it"? Is it giving any errors?

Comment: Can you please add `traceback` to your question if there is an error occuring and if I am understanding it right your `manage.py` is inside the `user` app/folder?

Comment: In the beginning it was giving **attempted relative import beyond top-level package** error when I was trying to import Product from product.models to cart.models in FK field. I fixed it with just taking product.Product into the quotes without any importing and it worked. But now I need to import Product model to my cart.views and when I'm trying to make **from product.models import Product** django isn't seeing it. So, the problem is that I'm not able to use Product model from product.models in cart.views. For now there is no error, I just need to find out how to import it